# How can I download items by ItemType filter from QuickBooks for Window

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I want to download item from Intuit data service (IDS) for windows by using Item type filter .
Like how can I query (post data) to download/retrieve only Inventory and Service item from QBDesktop using sync manager and IDS.

Reference links: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Item

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0200_Key_Concepts/0200_Custom_Fields/Data_Services_Custom_Fields#Retrieving_and_Filtering_Objects_With_Custom_Fields

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, then there is no query filter that will just get items where type=service or type-inventory, you need to query them all and filter the data on your side.

The v3 version of the API provides Simple Query Language where you will be able to provide the query you are asking, but the v3 is only in early beta for external partners today.

jarred